# web3.eth.accounts[0] returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I am new to solidity and was exploring it through a simple webapp. I have a web app which accepts some details and a button pressing which the details should be deployed to the block created by the smart contract. The details are successfully deployed from the remix IDE but give the following exception when entering through the web app.

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (inpage.js:1)
at u.validateArgs (inpage.js:1)
at u.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):231)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

On surfing the internet I found that this could be because the `web3.eth.accounts[0]` returns '**undefined**' which is what is happening in my case.

On the contrary though on displaying `web3.eth` on the console it does show accounts and the **MetaMask** address too at index 0.
I read it may be because `web3js 1.0` might not be completely supported by MetaMask yet but I am unable to find a solution to it.

Also how to check the version of web3 I am using and how to deprecate to lower if necessary.

This is how I try to access the `web3.eth.accounts[0]`

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount);  // returns undefined
```

I also tried the following method but to no avail:

```
var myAccount;
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,res){
     if(!err)
     {
        myAccount = res;
        console.log(myAccount);
     }
});
```

This returns the account address but the myAccount variable again returns '**undefined**' when used outside the getAccounts method. Also writing the further logic inside the if part does not help giving the above mentioned exception.

I have tried a few things but unable to find the solution. Please guide and correct if I have miss-understood anything.

**EDIT**

You can find the source code here. 
https://github.com/anishsamant/Solidity-Demo

Refer **Courses.sol** for solidity file
Refer **index.html** for web app.

Comment: Where do you deploying it? And can you show your constructor function's source code?

Comment: Since you're using the async way of web3.eth.getAccounts, the variable will only be defined inside the scope of the callback. In other words, you have to put all of your code inside that function. Beware, this could send you to http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: I tried putting my further logic inside that function but it still gives the above mentioned exception.

Comment: try changing the privacy mode settings on Metamask

Answer (score 4):

Methods in web3 such as getAccounts are asynchronous.

**Note**
web3 version 1.x.x return promises. So you use promises and you can also implement it with the async/await syntax.

web3 versions 0.x.x do not return promises, you can only use callbacks.

Code for web3 versions 1.x.x (I can only assume you might be using).

```
const myFunc = async () => {
    try {
        const myAccounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log(myAccounts)
        return myAccounts;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

myFunc()
```